# Can you set embedded services chat to automatically open the pre-chat form if agents are available?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, chat, pre-chat, embedded-services

Basically the title.  I've got my chat configuration all set up how the stakeholders want it, but they're asking if there's a way that the Pre-Chat form can automatically open in the page that we have embedded services set to run on if agents are logged into Omni-Channel and able to receive.  Since we always have agents available 24/7 there's no need for the check before loading the form, so they want to remove the unnecessary extra step of having the user have to click the button and just present them with the form directly as soon as the host page loads.  I haven't found anything in the documentation which would support this, so any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this if your chat instance is on a web page and not on a community.

You can use the [custom chat events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_chat_events.htm) with the [bootstrap api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_bootstrap_chat.htm)

Example

```
embedded_svc.addEventHandler("onSettingsCallCompleted", function(data) {
    console.log("onSettingsCallCompleted event was fired. Agent availability status is " + data.isAgentAvailable ? "online": "offline");
    embedded_svc.bootstrapEmbeddedService();
});
```